# Three periods syntax in Vuex?

Tags: vuex

I'm not solid on what mapstate does, other than that, what would ... mean in front of it. I don't see this nowhere as much within the guide as in example repos.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    messages: state => state.messages
  })
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you are building a large application by using Vuex,

you would have to manage your store in one place instead of separate them,

for example you have a large store and there's many states in the store:

```
const store =
{
    states: 
    {
        todo:
        {
             notes   : { ... },
             username: { ... },
             nickname: { ... }
        },
        checklist:
        {
             list: { ... }
        }
    } 
}
```

if you want to use them, you could **just do this**

```
computed:
{
    ...mapState(['todo', 'checklist'])
}
```

so **you don't** have to

```
computed:
{
    todo()
    {
        return this.$store.state.todo
    },
    checklist()
    {
        return this.$store.state.checklist
    }
}
```

and then use them like this:

```
todo.notes
todo.usernames
checklist.list
```

Comment: I would add that you could actually just do `computed: mapState(['todo'])` but than you couldn't have local computed properties, by using the three dots (spread operator) (wrapped in curly braces you include all props of mapState in your object and can then define additional local properties..so it's merging both objects kind of like `Object.assign()`

Comment: @CanRau You should put your comment into the Answer! It took me a day trying to figure out why do we need using Spread Synxtax in mapGetters or mapState, etc. In the Vuex docs, the example is very short and unclear. I had no idea can we use directly it like `computed: mapState([ ])` or `computed: getters([ ])` when we dont have any local computed properties or not

Comment:  Good point, thanks for taking the time to do it so people can find it quicker 

Answer (score 6):

As @Can Rau had answered, I will try to make more clear about what the h3ll is Spread Syntax `...` actually do in `mapGetter`, `mapState` and `mapActions` in Vuex.

Firstly, You can use directly `mapState` as: `computed: mapState` without Spread Syntax `...` when you don't have any local computed properties.

The same with `mapGetters` and `mapActions`

```js
computed: mapState({
    count: state => state.count,
    },

computed: {
  ...mapState({
     count: state => state.count,
  })
}
```

Both of the above do exactly the same thing!

But when you do have any local computed property, then you need Spread Syntax.

It because the mapState returns an object.
And then we need Object Spread Operator to merge multiple Objects into one.

```js
computed: {
  localComputed () { /* ... */ },
  // mix this into the outer object with the object spread operator
  ...mapState({
    // ...
  })
}
```

You can read more about **Spread in object literals** in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Basically, in this situation, it used to merge objects

```js
let obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
let copy = {...obj}
// copy is {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

//without ..., it will become wrong
let wrongCopy = {obj}
// wrongCopy is { {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} } - not what you want
```

And the [Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) explains this quite clear. Take a look more deeply and you will get the idea.